# how to check the Webbrowser document is completed loaded?

Tags: c#, browser, mshtml

I have a application which loads iframes dynamically when the page is loaded.
When I do automation of that application with Web browser control, I am getting script error, because the java script is not fully loaded in the iframe.

I am checking the ready state of the browser in DocumentCompleted event, still no luck...

```
 if (this.browser.ReadyState != System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            return;
        else
        {
 // do automation
  }
```

Comment: to do it properly, check out some of the hints i provide in some of my previous answers, unfortunately, the available methods online are not anywhere near reliable enough, but if you implement the ideas i've provided under tag webbrowser-control you will get a better idea on how to do it reliably.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code, encapsulte this in boolean property

```
            if (this.WebBrowser.ReadyState != System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                return false;

            if (this.HtmlDomDocument == null)
                return false;

            foreach (IHTMLDOMNode node in this.HtmlDomDocument.all)
            {
                IHTMLFrameBase2 frame = node as IHTMLFrameBase2;
                if (frame != null)
                {
                    if (!frame.readyState.Equals("complete", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
```